# NSWindow crashes after close and reopen

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I have created an NSWindow

```
self.storeWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 800, 660) styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskResizable|NSWindowListOrderedFrontToBack|NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:false];
                             [self.storeWindow setDelegate:self];
```

Which opens fine and closes fine. However if I call if again of even check for nil it crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I declare it as a string property in the header

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSWindow *storeWindow;
```

```
      if (self.storeWindow.contentView == nil) {
                            self.storeWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 800, 660) styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskResizable|NSWindowListOrderedFrontToBack|NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:false];
                             [self.storeWindow setDelegate:self];
                        }
                        [self.storeWindow setBackgroundColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
                        self.store = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 850, 640)];
                        [self.store loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:json[@"url"]]]];
                        [self.storeWindow.contentView addSubview:self.store];
                        [self.storeWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self.window];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the window owned by a window controller?  Is the window’s `releasedWhenClosed` property set?

Comment: It is not owned by a controlled.  The property releasedWhenClosed is just a getter, it currently reads ```(lldb) po self.storeWindow.isReleasedWhenClosed
<object returned empty description>
```

Comment: The property can also be set to change the default behavior, which is to release the window when it is closed.

Comment: Are you able to post a snippet to set it? Ive tried and it will not let me. Default is set to true, as per the docs.

Comment: The property is `releasedWhenClosed`, so it should be something like `self.storeWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO`

Comment: You are an amazing person. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSWindow’s [releasedWhenClosed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419062-releasedwhenclosed?language=objc) property can be set to change the default behavior, which is to release a window when it is closed (unless it is owned by a window controller).  The property can be set in the Interface Editor’s Attributes Inspector, or programmatically, for example:

```
[myWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
```