# How to reopen a window in macOS after closing it by clicking on close using swift Programatically

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

When X(close button) of window is clicked, window is being close, When I try to reopen the window I get bad access error. Please find my below code

```
var window: NSWindow!
func openWindow()
{    
if window == nil {
window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 550, height: 300),
                          styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .titled],
                          backing: .buffered, defer: false)
window.center()
window.title = "Open Network Share Url's"
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
window.isReleasedWhenClosed = true
window?.contentViewController = myViewController
} else {
     window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
                }
}
```

I am getting below error **Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).**

Comment: If you catch the crash in a debugger, where in your code does it happen? Could it be because `window` is closed and invalid, but not equal to `nil`?

Comment: Window is not becoming nil that's the problem. How can I handle it

Comment: Catch the closing of it, and set `windows` to `nil`? While i'm not experienced in macOS, I don't know of any other GUI environment which doesn't have a "window closed" type of event.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSWindow crashes after close and reopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56654410/nswindow-crashes-after-close-and-reopen)

Comment: Yes, I have set window.releasedWhenClosed = false. It worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.releasedWhenClosed = false
```

solved my issue